# how to compress the image size in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, html5

I can upload 1 MB images in visual force, it will be store in Document Object. Other wise if i Upload more then 1 MB images in Visual force page It will be Display Error Message

Comment: @ Nick Cook,  Thank you for your response,  we have 500 Kb Image, Once we click the Uploaded Button , The Image will be compressed to Display in visualforce page and Saved in Attachments please give any suggestions..

Comment: @Abdulmasood, Did u check the link provided by Nick?

Comment: Yes @Robert thomas ..  I Checked that link. That is not working properlly .. i means not selected / uploaded images .. and also i want to be compress the image size Thanks also not match i scenario          ----- See the above image

Answer (score 3):

The Salesforce server-side-language Apex does not include the byte-level access that would be needed to implement compression there (or include an API for image compression). That leaves you with choices such as:

- Do the compression on the client-side in JavaScript
- Make a HTTP callout on the server-side to a service such as https://tinypng.com/developers (there is a charge for that but it is very small)

From a quick Google the former approach looks like the first one to try. In particular there is this open-source JavaScript you could use https://github.com/brunobar79/J-I-C. There is a demonstration of that at http://makeitsolutions.com/labs/jic/. (I have not tried it so can't offer any help on it.)

Comment: any one can you please give some suggestions of above requirement....